# How to prevent XSS while creating a redirect path using window.location.replace()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, user-interface, xss

I have used window.location.replace() for redirection based on user's input. From a security review, this has been flagged as vulnerable to DOM based XSS. I am a newbie and I am not sure which part of the attached snippet is vulnerable and how to resolve this vulnerability.

Any leads and help on this is greatly appreciated.

```js
var a = $('input[name="a"]').val();
        var b = $('select[name="b"] option:selected').html();
        var c = $('select[name="c"] option:selected').val();
        var host = $(location).attr('protocol') + "//" + $(location).attr('host') + "/debug";
        if(!a) {
            return false;
        }       
        host += "/" + a;
        if(b && "Select" != b) {
            host += "/" + b;
        }
        if(c) {
            host += "/" + c;
        }
        window.location.replace(host);
```